# In performance test , what happen if the test will take 10 second and duration will finished in 5 minutes?

Tags: performance, jmeter, loadrunner, jmeter-5.0

My scenario is , I record a test and it will take 10 second to finish ,after that I put a duration and make it 5 minutes , so my question is , is my test will be take time same as duration ? or the test will be finished in 10 second but the result will display after 5 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Test will be finished:

- When the last [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) is executed
- Or the time set in "Duration" passes

whatever comes the first

If you have only 1 loop on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level - all the samplers will be executed once, if you have 2 loops - they will be executed twice, etc. The "duration" constraint is applicable at any case.

More information: [Getting Started with JMeter - A Basic Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/getting-started-jmeter-basic-tutorial)